# Eclipse add plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi

I have installed Eclipse Helios. how can i add to it plug-in development functionallity (to be able to create OSGi bundles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the below steps to Install **PDE(Plug-in Development Environment)** plugin in Eclipse:

1. Go to Help -> Eclipse Matketplace
2. Type PDE in find textbox to search
3. You can see PDE Plus icon
4. Install it

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the **Plugin Perspective**

Usually you can try to get it via:

- Help->Install New Software
- **"Work With:"** -> **"--All Available Sites--"**
- type **"Plug-in"** into the filter box
- Open **"General Purpose Tools"** (may be called differently in your eclipse version!)
- install **"Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment"**

restart!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.vogella.de/articles/OSGi/article.html gives a pretty detailed overview on eclipse & OSGi.

Comment: Thanks! But in my configuration of Eclipse there are not plug-in development functionality, how to add it to installed Eclipse?

Comment: If you're just creating OSGi bundles you should just be able to use a regular installation of eclipse -- create a plug-in project. If you plan on using RCP when creating the plugins you'll want to install "General Purpose Tools" -> "Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment" and "Eclipse RCP Plug-in Developer Resources" from the update site. You can do so by going to Help -> Install New Software and selecting the Eclipse helios site from the dropdown box, then filtering by RCP.

Comment: In my Eclipse there are not type of project - Plug-in development, how can I add this functionality without reinstall eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of eclipse did you download? It should be under "File" -> "New" -> "Other" -> "Plugin Project"

Comment: I didn't download, it was before me. 
In menu "File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> there are only "General", "CVS", "Java", "SVN", "Examples"

Answer (score 0):

I think the best and easiest way is to download another package that already have PDE installed:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
chose "Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers" or "Eclipse Modeling Tools", both are OK.